# Подключение динамической библиотеки linux в си

Tags: linux, c, ubuntu, library, dynamic

Подскажите, кто может. Не могу использовать собственную динамическую библиотеку.
Пишу на си библиотеку сортировок (курсовой проект), нужно обязательно использовать динамическую библиотеку. Собираю проект с помощью make.

```
APP_NAME = sortapp
LIB_NAME = libsort

CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
CPPFLAGS = -I src -MP -MMD

BIN_DIR = bin
OBJ_DIR = obj
SRC_DIR = src

APP_PATH = $(BIN_DIR)/$(APP_NAME)
LIB_PATH = $(OBJ_DIR)/$(SRC_DIR)/$(LIB_NAME)/$(LIB_NAME).so

SRC_EXT = c

APP_SOURCES = $(shell find $(SRC_DIR)/$(APP_NAME) -name '*.$(SRC_EXT)')
APP_OBJECTS = $(APP_SOURCES:$(SRC_DIR)/%.$(SRC_EXT)=$(OBJ_DIR)/$(SRC_DIR)/%.o)

LIB_SOURCES = $(shell find $(SRC_DIR)/$(LIB_NAME) -name '*.$(SRC_EXT)')
LIB_OBJECTS = $(LIB_SOURCES:$(SRC_DIR)/%.$(SRC_EXT)=$(OBJ_DIR)/$(SRC_DIR)/%.o)

DEPS = $(APP_OBJECTS:.o=.d) $(LIB_OBJECTS:.o=.d) $(TST_OBJECTS:.o=.d)

.PHONY: all
all: $(BIN_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR) $(SRC_DIR) $(RES_DIR) $(APP_PATH)

-include $(DEPS)

$(APP_PATH): $(APP_OBJECTS) $(LIB_PATH)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -O0 $^ -L$(OBJ_DIR)/$(SRC_DIR)/$(LIB_NAME) -lsort -o $@

$(LIB_PATH): $(LIB_OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared -o  $(LIB_PATH) -g $^

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -fPIC -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -g -o $@
```

всё проходит успешно, но при запуске программы выдаёт сообщение:
./sortapp: error while loading shared libraries: obj/src/libsort/libsort.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Пытался изменять файл ect/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf, добавляя в него расположение своей библиотеки, затем обновляя список видимых библиотек командой ldconfig. При использовании команды ldconfig -p вижу, что конфиг библиотеку видит (нижняя строка), однако проблема не пропадает, по прежнему выдаёт ту же ошибку [image: ldconfig -p] Так же пытался настраивать переменную среды LD_LIBRARY_PATH [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что так же не дало результатов.
Ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: по умолчанию, в Linux, библиотеки ищутся в определенных местах. LD_LIBRARY_PATH или LD_PRELOAD и все будет ок.

Comment: сначала покажите свои команды сборки. нужны определённые ключи `-shared -fPIC`.

Comment: Изменил вопрос, добавил код makefile, ключи     -shared -fPIC присутствуют

Comment: Изменение переменной среды LD_LIBRARY_PATH, как и было показано выше не дало результатов

Comment: Вы заменили пути для LD_LIBRARY_PATH на свой. А надо добавить.

Comment: Изначально переменная среды пустая

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: imho в https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html все хорошо описано (кстати, обратите внимание на сборку с флагом `-rpath`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для устранения наблюдаемого вами эффекта оказалось достаточно
убрать `LIB_PATH` (сам .so файл) из списка аргументов линкера
(да, линкер стал умным и используемых вами флагов ему достаточно (теперь нет необходимости включать `-Wl,-soname,libsort.so`, рекомендуемых в [инструкции](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/))).

Т.е. **в ваш Makefile я внес только одно небольшое изменение**:

```
$(APP_PATH): $(APP_OBJECTS) $(LIB_PATH)
#   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -O0 $^ -L$(OBJ_DIR)/$(SRC_DIR)/$(LIB_NAME) -lsort -o $@
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -O0 $(APP_OBJECTS) -L$(OBJ_DIR)/$(SRC_DIR)/$(LIB_NAME) -lsort -o $@
```

а именно, заменил `$^` на `$(APP_OBJECTS)`.

После этого все заработало, независимо от расположения исполняемого файла и `libsort.so`.

```
avp@avp-desktop:~$ cd avp/hashcode/app_libso/ 
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode/app_libso$ rm obj/src/*/*.o
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode/app_libso$ 
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode/app_libso$ make
cc -fPIC -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I src -MP -MMD src/sortapp/tlib.c -g -o obj/src/sortapp/tlib.o
cc -fPIC -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I src -MP -MMD src/libsort/lib.c -g -o obj/src/libsort/lib.o
cc -shared -o  obj/src/libsort/libsort.so -g obj/src/libsort/lib.o
cc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I src -MP -MMD -O0 obj/src/sortapp/tlib.o -Lobj/src/libsort -lsort -o bin/sortapp
```

Теперь для чистого эксперимента перебросим исполняемый файл и .so в разные места

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode/app_libso$ mv obj/src/libsort/libsort.so /tmp
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode/app_libso$ mv bin/sortapp /tmp/tst/
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode/app_libso$
```

и запустим программу

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode/app_libso$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/  /tmp/tst/sortapp 
try .so lib2_test(/tmp/tst/sortapp)
lib2.so::lib2_test() called from /tmp/tst/sortapp using LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/
lib2_test() = 78
End
```

Как видите, работает. Теперь переместимся сами и запустим ее еще раз

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode/app_libso$ cd
avp@avp-desktop:~$ 
avp@avp-desktop:~$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/  /tmp/tst/sortapp 
try .so lib2_test(/tmp/tst/sortapp)
lib2.so::lib2_test() called from /tmp/tst/sortapp using LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/
lib2_test() = 78
End
```

А вот так ее видит `ldd`

```
avp@avp-desktop:~$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/  ldd /tmp/tst/sortapp 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff045f6000)
    libsort.so => /tmp/libsort.so (0x00007f9634385000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9633f94000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9634789000)
avp@avp-desktop:~$
```

Для тестирования я сделал в вашем проекте пару файлов -- аппликейшн `src/sortapp/tlib.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib2.h"

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  (void)ac;
  printf("try .so lib2_test(%s)\n", av[0]);
  printf("lib2_test() = %d\n", lib2_test(av[0]));

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

и библиотеку -- `src/libsort/lib.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "lib2.h"

int
lib2_test (const char *p)
{
  char *lp = getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
  
  return printf("lib2.so::lib2_test() called from %s using LD_LIBRARY_PATH=%s\n",
        p ? p : "(nil)", lp ? lp : "(nil)");
}
```

а также `src/lib2.h`

```
#ifndef _LIB2_H_
#define _LIB2_H_

int lib2_test (const char *prog_name);

#endif
```

К сожалению, почему именно так (как вы и наблюдали), т.е. вне зависимости от `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, программа видит .so только из "корневой папки", я не смог выяснить.

Видимо это происходит из-за того, что линкер сначала получает на вход сам .so файл, а потом ссылку на него, как на библиотеку. Однако,  механизм такого его поведения остается для меня загадкой.

Comment: @Neytral, я обновил ответ, у вас заработало?

Comment: Да, всё заработало! Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 1):

В итоге программа заработала. Но! Только из "корневой папки".
[image]
Так выглядит директория в которой лежит проект. src-исходники, obj-объектные файлы и библиотеки, в папке bin лежит только исполняемый файл.
Если я пытаюсь запустить программу, предварительно зайдя в папку bin, то ошибка повторяется, но если запускаю из корневой папки командой `bin/sortapp`, то всё работает. То есть одно из действий, которые я описывал в вопросе решили проблему, но не до конца. Объясните почему так происходит и как сделать, что бы программу можно было запускать из любой директории?

Comment: Не стоит задавать новые вопросы в ответе - вы можете отредактировать исходный вопрос.

Comment: Ну по факту решение нашлось, поэтому решил написать в ответ